# How to solve this using logical proof and prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic, artificial-intelligence

There are 3 rooms displaying the following notices on them.

Room 1 : Princess is not in this room. Room 2 : Princess is not in this room. Room 3 : Princess is not in Room 2.

Only one statement is true.

Please help!

Comment: Take a look at library clpb of SWI-Prolog

Comment: Looks like homework and this is just very simply stated with **Propositional calculus**. But you still provide nothing besides the task. No own ideas. I also strongly think the statement ```Only one statement is true.``` is wrong as there is a solution (actually: two) where all statements are true which is also more interesting.

Comment: @sascha: Without the constraint "Only one statement is true", there are exactly 4 different solutions in total, but only *one* where *all* statements are true.

Comment: @mat Maybe you are right, but can you elaborate? To my understanding there are exactly two solutions then: Princess in room 3; no Princess in room 3. There is no existential-like constraint.

Comment: @mat (Offt-opic) Your profile sounds interesting. Having some mathematical-optimization knowledge myself i wonder how tasks like ```optimization methods for efficient water distribution``` or any other on your list is approached using Prolog (which i'm not familiar with in practice; the general idea is clear). I assume there are still libraries like (MI)NLP-solvers and co. in use (in which case i don't see the immediate advatage of using Prolog; i'm more of a Python + C/C++ user)? Any short description / or paper reference possible? Where does Prolog help?

Comment: @sascha, you are right, there are two solutions (not only one)! However, there are actually infinitely many: What about princess in room 4?

Comment: @mat Sure. It's all about assumptions as the model is not that formal. I assumed there are only 3 rooms = 3 binary variables/states.

Comment: @sascha, for combinatorial optimization methods, many Prolog systems provide dedicated libraries. For example, check out `library(clpfd)` in SICStus Prolog, which ships with state of the art algorithms for scheduling and allocation. If you are interested in these topics, the constraint libraries are where it's at, most notably CLP(FD), CLP(Q) and CLP(B). Problems that are highly combinatorial in nature are often more naturally modeled and solved with CLP(FD) than with integer linear programming, also since CLP(FD) provides dedicated algorithms (via specialised constraints) for various tasks.

Comment: @mat Thanks! I will check these *engines*. As i did a lot of SAT-modelling i can feel the advantage in highly combinatorial tasks but i also know how fast this approach renders infeasible (classic n out of k constraints hurt; despite more modern formulations and the concept of SMT-solvers). I just thought, that most of your problems sound only partially combinatorial. But thanks for the insight!

Comment: @sascha: You are definitely right: Many of these tasks have natural smooth variants and can be solved with simplex and other well-known methods. In CLP(B), check out the `card/2` constraint to model "n out of k" efficiently using BDDs. For example, in this case, I used: `?- sat(S1 =:= ~Room1), sat(S2 =:= ~Room2), sat(S3 =:= ~Room2), sat(card([1],[S1,S2,S3])).` to obtain: `S1 = Room2, Room2 = 1, Room1 = S2, S2 = S3, S3 = 0`. As you correctly point out, this still admits at least 2 solutions even *including* the cardinality constraint! Thus, it's a rather carelessly formulated task.